# MVC Knockout Databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am still new to Knockout. So pardon my ignorance. Here's my code.

C# class:

```
public class Person
    {

        public int Person_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<Phone> PhoneNumbers;
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<ul id="items" data-bind="foreach: person">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="item-meta" data-bind="text: $data.Name"></div>
            <div class="item-action">
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Email"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function PersonViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.person = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON(baseUri, self.person); 
}
```

How do iterate through the Phone list. I can see the JSON data coming through in Firebug.

TIA

Comment: did you try a `foreach`

Comment: You mean foreach: person.PhoneNumbers?? I tried that this way - <ul id="items2" data-bind="foreach: resume.employements">

Comment: Are you seeing data in the observable or just a serialized object. In firebug you should be able to set a breakpoint on the function and then using the console type something along the lines of self.person()[0].Email() to see the actual value. If that is the case then it may be in the bindings. since you have the context set to person you shouldn't need to use $data. In your code you don't have the ko.applyBindings(PersonViewModel) listed but I am assuming you have that as part of the js file correct?

Comment: I think this is similar to what you're looking for: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

Comment: I have the applybinding in place. So the name and email at person level displays just fine. I am unable to iterate through the phone data.

Comment: @rlcrews - Thanks a lot. That did it. Learned something new today.

Comment: have you tried to evaluate the foreach by chaining it to foreach: person()

Comment: @Lin Thanks a lot for the link. It helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First I would create a `Person` js object (I have used Id rather than Person_Id, in this 
example):

```
var Person = function (Id, Name, Email, PhoneNumbers) {
    self = this;
    self.Id = Id;
    self.Name = Name;
    self.Email = Email;        
    self.PhoneNumbers = ko.observableArray(PhoneNumbers);
}
```

Then a mapping, to create `Person` objects from the json:

```
    var mapping = {
        'People': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new Person(options.data.Id, options.data.Name,     
                  options.data.Email, options.data.PhoneNumbers);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then map your view model from actual json and apply the bindings.
I have used some pre-created json here for demo purposes containing 2 people:

```
    var data = {"People" : [{"Id": 1, "Name":"aName", "Email":"a@a.com", 
"PhoneNumbers":["123", "456", "789"]}, {"Id": 2, "Name":"bName", "Email":"a@a.com",
"PhoneNumbers":["123", "456", "789"]}] };

    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The above data variable in MVC could be populated from an ajax request:

```
$.getJSON(baseUri, function( data ) {
      var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Or populated from your returned model:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Finally I would use a template to display the data like this (again simplifed html for 
demo, you would add your html markup):

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', foreach:People }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
<span data-bind="text: Id" ></span><br/>    
<span data-bind="text: Name" ></span><br/>        
<span data-bind="text: Email" ></span><br/>        
<select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: PhoneNumbers"> </select>
</script>
```

Here is a working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qsjz/23/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this JS Fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/aeHr7/

I don't know if its complete code but you may be missing the KO binding.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.person = ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'Bert',   Email: 'xx@abc.com'
    }, {
        name: 'Charles',
        Email: 'xx@abc.com'
    }, {
        name: 'Denise',
        Email: 'xx@abc.com'
    }]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

you can have view model to accept your JSON data, feed that data to the person observableArray() and that should do the trick.